# aws_eks_cluster.this: error creating EKS Cluster (test-eks-lWuwSgqK): InvalidParameterException: Error in role params status code: 400

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I have issues
with deploying a test environment from the example provided in this community terraform-aws-eks module.

Cluster creation fails because of invalid role parameters.

```
...
module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.this: Creating...
  arn:                                        "" => "<computed>"
  certificate_authority.#:                    "" => "<computed>"
  created_at:                                 "" => "<computed>"
  endpoint:                                   "" => "<computed>"
  name:                                       "" => "test-eks-lWuwSgqK"
  platform_version:                           "" => "<computed>"
  role_arn:                                   "" => "arn:aws:iam::388030365049:role/test-eks-lWuwSgqK20181120125058962600000001"
  version:                                    "" => "1.10"
  vpc_config.#:                               "" => "1"
  vpc_config.0.security_group_ids.#:          "" => "1"
  vpc_config.0.security_group_ids.3345499915: "" => "sg-0440b523195e2b0ab"
  vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.#:                  "" => "3"
  vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.1248930552:         "" => "subnet-0726008335a5d88d5"
  vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.2473547375:         "" => "subnet-0fc6f4d85a453dbd5"
  vpc_config.0.subnet_ids.3955092080:         "" => "subnet-08c3c49b6442780ec"
  vpc_config.0.vpc_id:                        "" => "<computed>"
....
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.this: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_eks_cluster.this: error creating EKS Cluster (test-eks-lWuwSgqK): InvalidParameterException: Error in role params
    status code: 400, request id: f57ed2d0-ecc2-11e8-9fa6-b5608af2307c
```

Using the eks_test_fixture:
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/master/examples/eks_test_fixture

**Environment details**

Affected module version: 1.7.0.

OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.1

Terraform version: 0.11.10

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What AWS provider version are you using?

Comment: Terraform v0.11.10
+ provider.aws v1.46.0
+ provider.local v1.1.0
+ provider.null v1.0.0
+ provider.random v1.3.1
+ provider.template v1.0.0

Comment: Can you paste the exact code of your module here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reconfigure the IAM roles, user and policy.

Example:

```
module "xxxxx" {
  source                               = "git@github.com:terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks.git?ref=v1.7.0"
  cluster_name                         = "xxxx-xxxx"
  subnets                              = ["${module.vpc1.private_subnets}"]
  vpc_id                               = "${module.vpc1.vpc_id}"
  map_roles                            = "${local.eks_map_roles}"
...
}

locals {
  eks_map_roles = [
    {
      role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/xxxxx"
      username = "admin:{{SessionName}}"
      group    = "system:masters"
    },
    {
      role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/xxxxxxx"
      username = "admin:{{SessionName}}"
      group    = "system:masters"
    },
  ]
}
```